# if isset statement is incorrect

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to check if the reaction count is 0 then go in the if statement. The part without `&& ($app->count_reactie($topic['id']) == 0)` does work but when I add this it won't work.

In the line above this code I use: `implode($app->count_reactie($topic['id']))`and it works so it is not that this code doesnt work. This code will return the number of reactions.

But this code down below is what I am trying to get to work.

```
if(isset($actiefboardid)){
  $toppic = $app->get_topics($actiefboardid);
    foreach($toppic as $topic){
    if(isset($_SESSION['klant_id']) && ($_SESSION['klant_id'] == $topic['klant_id']) && ($app->count_reactie($topic['id']) == 0)){ 

}}}
```

Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: "works" and "doesn't work" aren't particularly meaningful descriptions.  And it seems *extremely unlikely* that you've discovered a bug in `isset()` and *far more likely* that you've made a mistake somewhere.  What is the *specific* problem you're having?

Comment: The part that you are adding has nothing to do with `isset`. Please describe the issue with more detail.

Comment: @David it will not go in the `isset()`so somehow their is something wrong with this: `&& ($app->count_reactie($topic['id']) == 0)`

Comment: can you var_dump ($app->count_reactie($topic['id']), to see what exactly it is.

Comment: @KawaljeetSingh the var dump will give me back: `array(1) { ["COUNT(reactie)"]=> string(1) "0" }` so it is set to 0.

Comment: var_dump($topic) and paste the result

Comment: it will return loots of thing but also the ID i need. But you thing their is something wrong with that? I doubt it

Comment: "surely the function that has existed for 3 major versions is faulty and not my beginner code"

Comment: can you var dump $topic please?

Comment: `array(13) { ["id"]=> string(2) "31" ["ledenpagina_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["klant_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["board_id"]=> string(2) "14" ["topicnaam"]=> string(4) "cdcd" ["omschrijving"]=> string(3) "ddd" ["positie"]=> string(0) "" ["url"]=> string(4) "cdcd" ["aanmaaktijd"]=> string(19) "2018-05-18 14:21:53" ["foto"]=> string(11) "1willie.jpg" ["voornaam"]=> string(3) "###" ["board_naam"]=> string(6) "Henkie" ["achternaam"]=> string(4) "###" }` this is what I get when I `var_dump($topic);` @delboy1978uk

Comment: Right so the ID is ok then, 31. Now you need to find out what the code inside count_reactie is doing/returning

Comment: @delboy1978uk If I var_dump the code it will return me this: `array(1) { ["COUNT(reactie)"]=> string(1) "0" }` for example

Comment: ok i added an answer, give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$count = $app->count_reactie($topic['id']);

if(isset($_SESSION['klant_id']) && ($_SESSION['klant_id'] == $topic['klant_id']) 
&& ($count['COUNT(reactie)'] == 0)){
```

Comment: Thanks mate! You are the only one who still believed in this question ! I hope you enjoy your life and don't die in a stupid car excedent or something! But thanks for the help mate!

Comment: if I could I would, need 15 reputation for that

Comment: geen probleem dan, de volgende keer!